# Alerts for External Lists

Tags: 2013, no-code-solution

I'm trying to turn on alerts for an external list (pointing to a table in SQL Server). When I do so, I get the following error "Alerts are not enabled on this list. Please contact the site administrator to ensure the backend supports alerts and the feature 'External System Events' is enabled on this site and try again."

How do I enable External System Events?
Is there a code free solution to sending users alerts for changes to external tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How do I enable External System Events?**

Unfortunately , you can't use alerts with external list, it's not supported . for more details check [External List Limitations in SharePoint 2010/2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2013/01/01/external-list-limitations-in-sharepoint/)

**Is there a code free solution to sending users alerts for changes to external tables?**

Fortunately, In Sharepoint 2013 , you can use Event Receiver on external lists, so try to handle the alerts that you need at item added or updated events in your code , for more details check [How to: Create external event receivers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163976.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! How about attaching a workflow to the forms for that list? i.e. I want to kick off a workflow when a user edits or adds a new record to the list.

Comment: Dear @BrendanMiller in SharePoint 2013 , as I mentioned in external list limitation article ,  Workflows cannot be configured for External Lists
Unfortunately, as you can see you cannot actually run a workflow on an external list. You neither have the option to define any workflows nor can you actually start one.doesn’t matter, External List = No Workflows!

Comment: Also Microsft said at offical article that Workflow doesn’t support external list in SharePoint 2013
Workflow in SharePoint 2010 supported create, read, update, delete (CRUD) operation for external list but SharePoint 2013 workflow doesn’t support CRUD operation for external list due to platform limitation. for more details check https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-Server-2013-known-issues-780242a6-236e-4d7a-8379-118a1aaa2a51?CorrelationId=fd9cf927-1a2c-493c-9556-6f470806f92c&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#_SharePoint_Designer